# Baking AO and Shadows into one image?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, image, texture-baking

I know how to bake simple AO maps inside Blender, but in this case I would like my AO map to include shadows casted by all the trees leaves. I've googled to find an answer about it, but I haven't found anything yet

Is this possible? I'm using Blender 2.66.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bake out the [ambient occlusion and shadow](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Bake#Bake_Mode) maps, then multiply them together in the compositor or your favourite image editor.